# IPTABLES forward all ports except ssh

Tags: linux, iptables

I have nat and packet routing working just fine, but I'd like to forward all ports except SSH to a static ip(192.168.0.3)

What would be the correct iptables syntax to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the *iptables* rules are executed in order (the first match applies, the following rules are not even tested), you can do it as follows:

```
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 192.168.0.2 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.3
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 192.168.0.2 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.3
 iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -d 192.168.0.2 --dport 22 -j REJECT
 iptables -A FORWARD  -i eth0 -d 192.168.0.2 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

having assumed that the pc on which you are doing this has IP address 192.168.0.2, otherwise change it accordingly. THe last rule is needed to assure connectivity of the pc with IP address 192.168.0.3.

Comment: is eth0 the WAN or LAN interface?

Comment: @MMavipc I assumed eth0 to be the WAN interface

Comment: Just for clarification, this will only forward the ports to 192.168.0.3 right? I have 192.168.0.0/16 NATed

Comment: @MMavipc Right. If you have already natted 192.168.0.0/16, then you probably do not need the last iptables rule.

Comment: The first two commands appear to be identical; what am I missing?  Also, since the third command uses `--dport`, doesn't it need to say `-p tcp` (or `-p udp`)?

Comment: it looks like these rules will drop port 22 rather than leave it un-NATted. The OP didn't specify what he wanted but it would seem like he wanted to leave the router accessible by SSH.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer being overly complex, and somewhat outdated with the release of [nftables](https://www.nftables.org/), here is my take on the issue, which is complex in another way, but complete:

### sysctl settings

Enable IPv4 and IPv6 forwarding (also known as Network Address Translation (NAT)):

```bash
sudo tee '/etc/sysctl.d/90-ip-forward.conf' << EOF
# Enable IPv4 forwarding (NAT).
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# Enable IPv6 forwarding (NAT).
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
EOF
```

Apply `sysctl` settings:

```bash
sudo sysctl --system
```

### Environment detection

Detect the outgoing network interface (i.e. Internet facing interface):

```bash
default_interface="$(command ip route show 'default' |
    command head --lines=1 |
    command cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=5)"
```

Detect the SSH daemon listening port:

```bash
sudo --validate &&
  sshd_port="$(sudo sshd -T -f '/etc/ssh/sshd_config' |
    grep "^port " |
    cut --delimiter=" " --fields=2)"
```

### Source NAT - Masquerade

Masquerade is a special case of SNAT, where the source address is "automagically" set to the address of the output interface.

Masquerading is the mechanic behind connection sharing.

> The masquerading rule is not part of the answer to the asked question,
> but is required for a working NAT setup.
> It gives access to Internet to the hosts behind the firewall,
> when coupled with a correctly set-up DHCP server
> or when using the firewall IP as the network gateway on these hosts.

With the legacy `iptables`, the rule for masquerading all outgoing traffic from the default network interface is:

```bash
sudo iptables --append 'POSTROUTING' --table 'nat' \
  --out-interface "${default_interface}" --jump 'MASQUERADE'
```

With the new `nftables`, the same rule installed in two parts.

1. Create the `source-nat` table, and add it as a postrouting hook (equivalent to `iptables --table 'nat'`:

   ```bash
   sudo nft add table 'source-nat'
   sudo nft add chain 'source-nat' postrouting '{ type nat hook postrouting priority 100 ; }'
   ```
2. Add the masquerading rule to the `source-nat` table for the default outgoing interface (or `oif`):

   ```bash
   sudo nft add rule 'source-nat' 'postrouting' oif "${default_interface}" 'masquerade'
   ```

### Forward all ports except SSH

With the legacy `iptables`, the rules for forwarding all ports except SSH (for a destination host with IP address `192.168.0.3`) are:

1. Add a rule forwarding all incoming TCP traffic to the destination IP address
   except the traffic targeting the SSH daemon port
   (`! --dport "${sshd_port}"`):

   ```bash
   sudo iptables --append 'PREROUTING' --table 'nat' \
     --in-interface "${default_interface}"
     --protocol 'tcp' ! --dport "${sshd_port}"
     --jump 'DNAT' --to "192.168.0.3"
   ```
2. Add a rule forwarding all incoming UDP traffic to the destination IP address:

   ```bash
   sudo iptables --append 'PREROUTING' --table 'nat' \
     --in-interface "${default_interface}" --protocol 'udp'
     --jump 'DNAT' --to '192.168.0.3'
   ```

With the new `nftables`, the same rule installed in two parts.

1. Create the `destination-nat` table, and add it as a prerouting hook (equivalent to `iptables --table 'nat'`:

   ```bash
   sudo nft add table 'destination-nat'
   sudo nft add chain 'destination-nat' prerouting '{ type nat hook prerouting priority -100; }'
   ```
2. Add the rule forwarding all incoming TCP traffic, SSH port excepted, to the `destination-nat` table for the default incoming interface (or `iif`):

   ```bash
   sudo nft add rule 'destination-nat' 'prerouting' iif "${default_interface}" \
     'tcp' dport != "${sshd_port}" dnat to '192.168.0.3'
   ```
3. Add the rule forwarding all incoming UDP traffic, SSH port excepted, to the `destination-nat` table for the default incoming interface (or `iif`):

   ```bash
   sudo nft add rule 'destination-nat' 'prerouting' iif "${default_interface}" \
     'udp' dnat to '192.168.0.3'
   ```

> I believe the two destination NAT rules could be combined in one when using `nftables`, but I've not yet found the correct solution.

Et voilà !

For more information on `nftables` NAT rules, see [Performing Network Address Translation (NAT) @ nftables](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Performing_Network_Address_Translation_(NAT)).